# MySQL query (over SSL) fails in IIS 7 using default AppPool identity

Tags: mysql, iis, ssl, .net

I am trying to run a website locally in Windows 7 under IIS 7. I have the AppPool configured to use "Classic" mode, but connecting to a MySQL DB that requires SSL fails. If I change the identity to my user account it works perfectly. It fails when using the default "ApplicationPoolIdentity" account. Is there something I'm missing somewhere? Why would running a MySQL query over SSL fail for certain user accounts?

**Update:** This is the exception that the MySQL Connector is throwing:
*"Reading from the stream has failed. Attempted to read past the end of the stream."*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you isolate the issue a bit further? Did you try accessing MySQL DB without SSL?
Also, one point to remember here is ApplicationPoolIdentity is not a normal User account, it's a build-in security account with least security privileges.

Comment: I can access MySQL without SSL.